# Drawing curve in Geogebra with arrow mark

Tags: plot, geometry, geogebra

I would like to draw the following picture in Geogebra with arrow mark showing the direction on curve as show in the figure

Image1

[image: 1]

I tried the following:

Image2

[image: 2]

Comment: Did you try making a very short vector along the tangent?